# Moved identical code from IBAction to method--produces different behavior

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview, ibaction

I have a button that seems superfluous. I want to remove the button and place its functionality (animating a simple bar chart with associated labels) into a method that gets called upon return from a user input view controller.

It seemed simple enough to rename the existing IBAction method and put the call to the replacement method into the delegate method that handles the transition back to the original View controller. However, this produced an unexpected result.

Here's a screenshot. The button in question is the red one (Show Graph):

[image]

The problem is that before the change, the two labels (`firstLabel` and `secondLabel`) over the bars would appear **after** the bars animate into position. After the method change (the creation code is unchanged), the labels appear instantly upon return to the VC, **before** the bars animate.

Here's the original IBAction method attached to the button:

```
- (IBAction)goButtonAction:(id)sender
{

    switch (goButtonKey)
    {
        case 0:
        {

        }
            break;

        case 1:
        {
            [self handleAvsAAction];
            [self doTheMathAvsA];
            [self makeBarChart];
        }

            break;

        case 2:
        {
            [self handleCvsCAction];
            [self doTheMathCvsC];
            [self makeBarChart];
        }


        default:
            break;
    }
    [self.goButton setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];

}
```

And here's the new method:

```
- (void) showGraph
{

    switch (goButtonKey)
    {
        case 0:
        {

        }
            break;

        case 1:
        {
            [self handleAvsAAction];
            [self doTheMathAvsA];
            [self makeBarChart];
        }

            break;

        case 2:
        {
            [self handleCvsCAction];
            [self doTheMathCvsC];
            [self makeBarChart];
        }


        default:
            break;
    }
    [self.goButton setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];

}
```

Here's the code (from `makeBarChart`) that produces the bar animation and the labels. For brevity, I'm just showing one bar--the other is essential identical, except being driven by different data:

```
    switch (thisRiser.tag)
    {
        case 1:
        {
            [self.chartView addSubview:firstLabel];
            [firstLabel setHidden:YES];


            [UIView animateWithDuration:.6
                                  delay:.2
                                options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                             animations:^
             {
                 // Starting state
                 thisRiser.frame = CGRectMake(35, self.chartView.frame.size.height, barWidth, 0);
                 thisRiser.backgroundColor = startColor1;

                 // End state
                 thisRiser.frame = CGRectMake(35, self.chartView.frame.size.height, barWidth, -focusBarEndHeight);
                 thisRiser.backgroundColor = endColor1;
                 thisRiser.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
                 thisRiser.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7;
                 thisRiser.layer.shadowRadius = 4.0;
                 thisRiser.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(5.0f, 5.0f);
                 thisRiser.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:thisRiser.bounds].CGPath;
             }
                             completion:^(BOOL finished)
             {


                 firstLabel.frame = CGRectMake(thisRiser.frame.origin.x, thisRiser.frame.origin.y - 65, barWidth, 60);
                 [firstLabel.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12]];
                 firstLabel.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
                 firstLabel.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
                 [firstLabel setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%.2f%%\nTime--%@",focusItemName,focusItemPercent,actualDurationFocusItem] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                 firstLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                 [firstLabel setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                 [firstLabel setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
                 [firstLabel setHidden:NO];
                 [firstLabel addTarget:self action:@selector(firstLabelAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                 [firstLabel setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
                 [thisRiser setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];


//                 NSLog(@"Done!");
             }];
        }
            break;
```

It doesn't seem reasonable that such a straightforward change would cause this effect. I've tried it several times to be sure I'm not breaking anything, and it seems that I am not.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried moving the code to viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear? Placing it there would be more like your original implementation (in terms of timing). It could be, by calling the methods from a delegate method, the frames are not set yet (it's not clear where you're calling the methods from)?

Comment: Do you mean the code in the completion block, or the entire animation, or make the call to makeBarChart in viewDidLoad? I just tested for "finished," BTW, and it's logging 0. The "makeBarChart" method is called by another method after the delegate (and after some considerable arithmetic).

Comment: I was thinking, putting all the code you originally had in the button method in viewDidAppear (not viewDidLoad) just because everything should be in the same state then as it would have been when you clicked on the button. You might need some sort of flag though, so it doesn't happen when the view first appears (if you don't want that).

Comment: Since I do use this VC to display two different types of data two different ways, I just put a call to the method containing the (former) button code in an "if" conditional with a flag in viewDidLoad. As things stand now, it's not working right (kinda backwards or something), but I'm going to mess with it for a little bit before giving it up. I'll post the results when I get it right, or when I give up, whichever comes first. Thanks for your suggestions--they are well taken.

Comment: @rdelmar--I just noticed you said viewDidAppear. Damn it, I just backed up to a snapshot before removing the button, but will try again with viewDidAppear. Sorry for my oversight!

Comment: @rdelmar--your suggestion worked perfectly, and it taught me a thing or two about viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear. Thanks! If you'd like to put your comments in an answer, I'll upvote and accept!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was resolved by moving the call to the code from the former button action method (refactored into showGraph) from `viewDidLoad` into `viewDidAppear, as suggested by @rdelmar in a comment. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to put all the code from "completion:^(BOOL finished)" block, inside an if statement:

```
completion:^(BOOL finished) {
  if (finished) {
    // Do all that stuff, including make the label visible...
  }
}
```